# Determine whether $\sum \frac{2^n + n^2 3^n}{6^n}$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2^n+n^23^n}{6^n},$$ I was thinking of using the root test? so then I would get $(2+n^2/n+3)/6$ but how do I find the limit of this?

Comment: Break it into $\sum\frac{2^n}{6^n}+\sum\frac{n^23^n}{6^n}$

Comment: You can't take roots the way you did.  $(a+b)^k ≠ a^k + b^k$

Comment: Even after the edit, you still can't take roots that way.  There is no particularly pleasant way to express the $n^{th}$ root of a sum of terms.

Comment: If root test is a problem, maybe try ratio test.

Comment: So I'm trying to use the ratio Test but I was wondering how I can simplify (n+1)^2(3)^n+1/(n^2)(3^n)

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the exact value of that sum. Since $\sum_{k\geq 0}x^k=\frac{1}{1-x}$ if |x|<1, uniformly in $k$, you can differentiate this expression to get $\sum_{k\geq 0}x^k=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$, differentiate to get an expression for $\sum_{k\geq 0}k^2x^k$, wherer |x|<1. In your case, $x=1/2$. The other portion is a geometric progression.

Answer (score 0):

We might compare and then apply either the root or ratio test, if these are your preferred tests. That is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2^n+n^23^n}{6^n} < \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{n^23^n + n^23^n}{6^n} = 2\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{n^2 3^n}{6^n} = 2\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{3^n},
$$
and you can now use either the root test or the ratio test (or perhaps a variety of other methods) to determine the convergence of the series.

Thematically, the exponential growth in the denominator is *so much larger* than the polynomial growth in the numerator of the original series that we can vastly overestimate like this and be fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac {n^4}{2^n} = 0$

$\implies $ After a particular value of $m \in \mathbb N :  n^4 << 2^n ~\forall~ n \ge m$ or

$\dfrac {n^4}{2^n}<1  ~\forall~ n \ge m$.

Hence, $\dfrac {n^2}{2^n} < \dfrac {1}{n^2} \implies \sum \dfrac {n^2}{2^n} <  \sum \dfrac {1}{n^2}    $

and $\sum \dfrac {1}{n^2}    $ is a convergent series.

Hence, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2^n+n^23^n}{6^n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac {1}{3^n} + \dfrac {n^2}{2^n}$ is convergent

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2^n+n^23^n}{6^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{n^2}{2^n}\right),$$

where

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^n}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{3}}-1=\frac{1}{2}$$

and, by ratio test,

$$\frac{\frac{(n+1)^2}{2^{n+1}}}{\frac{n^2}{2^n}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 \to \frac{1}{2}<1 \;\; \text{ as } \;\; n \to \infty,$$

meaning that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{2^n}$ is absolutely convergent. Therefore, the whole series is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n+n^2 3^n}{6^n}$$
I wouldn't recommend the root test for this series. However, here are the steps 
$$r=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{2^n+n^2 3^n}{6^n}\right|}$$
$$=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{2^n+n^2 3^n}}{\sqrt[n]{6^n}}$$
$$=\frac16\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(2^n+n^2 3^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
$$=\frac16\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(\log\left(2^n+n^2 3^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)$$
$$=\frac16\exp\left(\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log\left(2^n+n^2 3^n\right)\right)$$
$$=\frac16\exp\left(\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n\log 2+2n3^n+n^2 3^n\log 3}{2^n+n^2 3^n}\right)$$
$$=\frac16\exp\left(\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{2^n\log 2}{n^2 3^n}+\frac{2}{n}+\log 3}{\frac{2^n}{n^2 3^n}+1}\right)$$
$$=\frac16\exp\left(\log 3\right)=\frac36=\frac12$$
Note that $r\lt 1$, therefore
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n+n^2 3^n}{6^n}=\mbox{convergent} $$